# Rollover sum with grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to do Rollover sum with grouping in SQL Server

I need to sum of sales within same year for the later quaters.

Data is like shown below

> **Year               Qtr              sales**

```
2011         1        10

2011         2        5

2011         5        30

2012         4        30

2012         5        2
```

I would need the output like below

> **Year    |    quater    |       salestillnowThisYear**
>
> 2011          1        10
>
> 2011          2         15  (which is 10 + 5 from previous quaters within same year)
>
> 2011          5         45  ( 10 + 5 + 30 from previous quaters of this year)
>
> 2012          4         30
>
> 2012          4         32 (30 + 2 which is 30 from previous quater of this year)

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @RomanPekar its sql server 2012.

Comment: then the easiest one for you will be http://stackoverflow.com/a/10309947/1744834.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve `Rolling Sum`. Here are few options.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (years INT, id INT, sal INT )

INSERT #test
VALUES (2011,1,10),
       (2011,2,5),
       (2011,5,30),
       (2012,4,30),
       (2012,5,2)
```

**Method 1 :**  Using `Correlated Sub-Query`

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Sum(sal)
        FROM   #test b
        WHERE  a.years = b.years
               AND a.id >= b.id)
FROM   #test a
```

**Method 2:** Using `Inner Join`

```
SELECT a.years,
       a.id,
       Sum(b.sal) AS total
FROM   #test a
       INNER JOIN #test b
               ON a.id >= b.id
                  AND a.years = b.years
GROUP  BY a.years,
          a.id
```

**Method 3 :** Using `SUM()` with the `OVER() clause`. [Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189461.aspx) for more info on Over Clause

**[`SQL FIDDLE DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69d59/2)**

```
SELECT a.years,
       a.id,
       sal,
       Sum(sal)
         OVER(
           partition BY years
           ORDER BY id rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS runningtotal
FROM   #test
```

**Note:** `Method 3` solution works from `SQL SERVER 2012+`

Comment: @NoDisplayName Thanks for detail solution. i have modified your Method3 as 'partition by department,Years' as i have addition grouping category as department wise. Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

```
create table test(year1 int,quarter1 int,sales int)

insert into test
select 2011         ,1        ,10 UNION ALL

select 2011         ,2        ,5 UNION ALL

select 2011         ,5        ,30 UNION ALL

select 2012         ,4        ,30 UNION ALL

select 2012         ,5        ,2
```

Try this:

```
 SELECT a.year1
           , a.quarter1
           , SUM(b.sales) AS total

FROM test a INNER JOIN test b
     ON  a.quarter1 >= b.quarter1
     AND a.year1 = b.year1

GROUP BY a.year1
           , a.quarter1
ORDER BY a.year1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2011    1   10
2011    2   15
2011    5   45
2012    4   30
2012    5   32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sum() with Partition By`

```
select *,sum(sales)over(partition by Year order by Year) as salestillnowthis  from table
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039431/how-can-i-use-sum-over)