# Rollover sum with grouping in SQL Server with values repeating for empty fortnights

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to do Rollover sum with grouping in SQL Server with values repeating for empty fortnights

I need to sum of sales within same year for the later fortnights.

Data is like shown below

> **Year               fortnight              sales**

```
2011         1        10

2011         2        5

2011         5        30

2012         4        30

2012         5        2
```

I would need the output like below

> **Year    |    fortnight    |       salestillnowThisYear**
>
> 2011          1        10
>
> 2011          2         15  (which is 10 + 5 from previous fortnight within same year)
>
> 2011          3         15  same as previous fortnight
>
> 2011          4         15  same as previous fortnight
>
> 2011          5         45  ( 10 + 5 + 30 from previous quaters of this year)
>
> 2011          6         45  same as previous fortnight
>
> 2011          7         45  same as previous fortnight
>
> ......and so on for each fortnight till last fortnight
>
> 2011          24        45  last fortnight data
>
> 2012          4         30  note this is the fortnight which first has value
>
> 2012          5         32  (which is 10 + 5 from previous fortnight within same year)
>
> 2012          6         32  last fortnight data
>
> 2012          7         32  last fortnight data
>
> ......and so on for each fortnight till last fortnight
>
> 2012          24        32  last fortnight data

Below is the available solution with me.

> 1 .Create temp table (rpt_fortnight) with 24 rows to represent 24 fortnights
>
> 2. join the data with that rpt_fortnight table to get data for all fortnights as (step2result)

`SELECT YEar, fMaste.FortNightNumber as FortNightNumber,
       sales as     sales 
     FROM   data AS FNI 
            inner join 
    rpt_fortNight as fMaste

    on fMaste.FortnightNumber >= FNi.FortNightNumber --<--extrapolated data for next fortnights`

> 3.combined data for fortnights from previous fortnights if available

```
SELECT year,
       FortNightNumber,
       Sum(sales) as sales
 FROM   step2result
 group by   year,FortNightNumber
```

> 4. we shall get data for all next fortnights with sum of previous fortnights in step 3

I wanted to check if there was any better solution

Comment: Even though this question is similar to question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214819/rollover-sum-with-grouping-in-sql-server but output required is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `Recursive CTE` to generate years with 1 to 24 fortnight.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     years     INT,
     fortnight INT,
     sal       INT
  )

INSERT #test
VALUES (2011,1,10),
       (2011,2,5),
       (2011,5,30),
       (2012,4,30),
       (2012,5,2);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS fortnight,
                         years
         FROM   #test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT fortnight + 1,
                years
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  fortnight < 24),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT a.years,
                a.fortnight,
                Isnull(sal, 0) SAL
         FROM   cte A
                LEFT JOIN #test B
                       ON a.fortnight = b.fortnight
                          AND a.years = b.years)
SELECT *,
       Sum(sal)
     OVER(
       partition BY years
       ORDER BY fortnight rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Running_Total
FROM   CTE1 A
ORDER  BY years,
          fortnight
```

Comment: Thanks @NoDisplayName . Won't the last inline query will be a performance killer?

Comment: @DRAM - You can use any method of my previous answer in last select statement. Updated the answer.